# Jquery Ajax ignores request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#read').click(function () {
        $('#respond').html("Loading...");
        $.get("read_data.php", function(data) {
            $('#respond').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

The code above calls a simple php page to get data. It worked well on the first request but after that the code returned the same data even after I changed php file, removed the whole data source and changed the browser. It looks like if it cached the first request.

I've searched error logs but nothing has been found.
Also it responds very very fast even though the data and the page are both external.

Comment: Have your server instruct the client to not cache it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the browser having cached the data.  You can get around this by passing an additional parameter that the server side page can just ignore.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#read').click(function () {
        $('#respond').html("Loading...");
        $.get("read_data.php?rand="+Math.random(), function(data) {
            $('#respond').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

The random value will get passed and the browser will attempt to cache the data sent with the data received, but as every request is (effectively) unique, the browser can't load the cached data.

Answer (score 1):

Browser's usually cache `GET` requests unless otherwise specified or a query string is passed. Change your code to use `$.ajax` and set the `cache` parameter to `false`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#read').click(function () {
        $('#respond').html("Loading...");
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "read_data.php"
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#respond').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Internally, jQuery will add a `_={some random number}` query string parameter to the end of the request to prevent caching of the result.